# How to create a simple vote button

Tags: 7, rating

I'm trying to create a voting option for the nodes in my website. I want the voting to look like this

[image: Sample Voting Image]

The users click on the vote button and the number increases.

I have tried using the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module but it's not working with views or display suite. Is there any other module that I can use which will help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/Rate) module, and since you are using display suite, you can integrate it with it for nodes like so:

1. Create a rate widget at `admin/structure/rate`
2. Using Display Suite module, at the bottom of page, click on `Custom fields`
3. Click on `Add a code field`
4. Fill all the fields and check `Nodes` and on Code field copy and paste this:

   $widget_id = '1';
   print rate_generate_widget($widget_id, 'node', $entity->nid);

**remember to open and close PHP tag before and after the code, I can't paste that here.**

5. Hit save and now you can see there's a new field added to the list of fields you previously had on your `Manage Display` Page.
6. Re-Arrange the field to where you want it to be displayed and you are good to go.

Comment: I followed your instructions and I was able to get the field displayed on the Manage Display Page. But when I go on the node I'm getting these errors 'Undefined variable: entity in eval()' and 'Trying to get property of non-object in eval()'

Comment: I think you missed the first step of creating a widget

Comment: I did create a custom widget.

Comment: do you have entity module enabled ? also did you used open and close PHP tag before and after the code sample ?

Comment: Its working noW!! I must have missed something earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The [Plus One Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/plus1) (in conjunction with the [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi)) should do what you're looking for.

> [This module provides] a simple digg-like voting widget for content that uses Ajax.

Here is a [demo](http://brunellodev.info/drupal/node/1) I put together for [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90607/voting-a-post-several-times-by-same-user/).

Comment: I'm facing some problems with this. I have created a image gallery in views and the plus 1 widget does not appear